# Update Event SharePoint Calender C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, calendar, sharepoint-2013

I can create event on SharePoint calender using `C#` code , but is it possible to update this event using `C#`? I tried this code, to add the event as a new one but can't delete the old one using `C#`:

```
SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList(sCalendarName);
if (list != null)
{
   SPListItem item = list.Items.Add();
   item["Title"] = "New Event";
   item["Description"] = "New Event created using SharePoint Object Model";
   item["Location"] = "First Floor";
   item["EventDate"] = DateTime.Now;
   item["EndDate"] = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
   item["Category"] = "Business";
   item["fAllDayEvent"] = false;
   item["Author"] = web.EnsureUser(@"domen\username");
   item.Update();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how you should update. You should get the existing item and update it. If you know the ID of existing item, for example , if its 34:

```
SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(34);
   item["Title"] = "New Event";
   item["Description"] = "New Event created using SharePoint Object Model";
   item["Location"] = "First Floor";
   item["EventDate"] = DateTime.Now;
   item["EndDate"] = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
   item["Category"] = "Business";
   item["fAllDayEvent"] = false;
   item["Author"] = web.EnsureUser(@"domen\username");
   item.Update();
```

Update:

Check out the examples here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539976%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Check out

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.getitembyid%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: It's helpful , So How could I get the ID of the event that I want to edit could I retrieve it while Creating a new event and save it
also could I select this event using any thing else ?

Comment: Yes, when you do add and call item.Update. You can get the ID through item.ID

Comment: Thank you it's really Good but Could you help using an Example ??